# Showing that $(1+z)^a =e^{a\log(1+z)}$ for integer $a$ is equivalent to $(1+z)(1+z)(1+z)(1+z)...$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I was having trouble proving the above statement.

Say that we have principal branch of power function $(1+z)^a $ with domain $\mathbb C\setminus \{x+0i, x\leq 0 \}$.

Then how do we show that $(1+z)^a =e^{a\log(1+z)}$ for integer $a$ is equal to the expansion $(1+z)^a = (1+z)(1+z)(1+z)(1+z)...$?

Comment: Straightforward induction and properties of the exponential function

Comment: General proof needed $a^x=e^{alog(x)}$

Comment: For positive integer $a$, $$
e^{a\log (1 + z)}  = e^{\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^a {\log (1 + z)} }  = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^a {e^{\log (1 + z)} }  = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^a {(1 + z)}  = (1 + z)^a .
$$ For negative integers, take the reciprocal.

Comment: How about for negative integers? Maybe multiplying $1+z$ by $-1$ times is just dividing by $1+z$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I think the OP had positive integers in mind. Writing $(1+z)^a=(1+z)(1+z)\ldots$ for a negative $a$ is a bit confusing. Anyhow, I added something to my comment.